# How to cancel a prev request on server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In advance, I'm sorry for my english.

Keep to the point, I have got a script that works using AJAX. The users can send a lot of requests and when an user's sending a new request then previous request's canceled and it works properly on the client-side, but on a server (Apache) the previous request keeps on executing.

Can I cancel a previous request that's working on the server and how I have to do it?

Comment: Why do you have to cancel it? Do you have any code?

Comment: All requests that is being processed on the server take a great deal of time and if they won't be canceled then the server will be working uselessly

Comment: How do you cancel the ajax request on the client side? I haven't used `php`  for a while now, but a script should stop executing when the connection is closed as long as you don't call `ignore_user_abort` yourself.

Comment: I was looking for it: PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client.

Comment: I guess, my question can be closed. Thank you all